# Different Background Color For a React Component that Renders an array of Numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-redux

I was to generate different background colors in a React component that returns an array of numbers from 1 to 100.

The even numbers should have a separate color as well as Odd and Prime numbers.

Presently, I have my Random Component rending inside the App component.

My problem now is how to generate those colors for even, odd and prime numbers.

What I have done so far is down below.

**App Component**

```js
import React from 'react'
import Numbers from './Numbers'
import './Style.css'

export default function App() {
    // const numbers = [1]

const numbers = [];
for(let i=0; i<=31; i++){
    numbers.push(i);
    if(i % 2 === 0){
        // numbers.style.backgroundColor = 'green' ; 
    }
   }
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className="child">
          <h1>Numbers List</h1>
          <ul>
            <Numbers className="block" numbers={numbers} />
            {/* <Numbers/> */}
          </ul>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    )
}
```

**Number Component**

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function Numbers({ numbers }) {
  const list = numbers.map((number) => 
  <div key={number} className="numbers"><li  className="list">{number}</li></div>
  )
  return list
}
```

**Style sheet**

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
} 
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
} 
.numbers{
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid aliceblue;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
li{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: do you want  multiple colors or just 2 specific colors ?

Comment: Multiple colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Numbers({ numbers }) {
  const isPrime = num => {
  for(let i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
  }
  const isOdd = (num)=> { return num % 2;} 
  const getBackGroundColor = (num)=>{
       let color = 'red';
       if(isOdd (num)) color ='red' //even
       else color ='green' //odd
       if(isPrime(num)) color = 'orange' //prime 
    return color ;
  }

  const list = numbers.map((number) => 
  <div key={number} style={{backgroundColor: getBackGroundColor(number) }} className="numbers"><li  className="list">{number}</li></div>
  )
  return list
}
```

Comment: What about background colors for Odd, and prime numbers

Comment: Everything here is returning Yellow

Comment: my bad  I forgot and I assigned "orange" to color variable before returning it check the edit now

Answer (score 0):

The following css makes odd numbers background grey, even numbers bg silver, and prime numbers bg pink:

```
li:nth-child(2),
li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: pink;
}

li:first-child,
li:nth-child(3n+6),
li:nth-child(5n+10),
li:nth-child(7n+14)
{
  background: grey
}

li:nth-child(2n+4) {
  background: silver
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I call the random() function and it generates random color from the array.

```
const random = () => {
    const backgroundColor = ["#134563", "#27ae60", "#3263F3", "#FFDC61"];
    const randomColors = backgroundColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * backgroundColor.length + 0)];
    return randomColors;
  }
random();
```